# POST HTML/PHP form submission not displaying posted data

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having some trouble setting up a basic php form submission. Using the following code:

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

With the following php on the welcome php page.

```
Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The index page displays two forms with text fields which may be typed in, however when imputing text and clicking submit it takes me to the php page without sending any of the data.

Description is a bit vague, here is a gif to show what is happening:
https://gyazo.com/aa1c9df6b090600cbc403151df49f0e3

Comment: odd your running a php server?

Comment: Your code is working fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238342/php-post-doesnt-display-data-example-code-shown

Comment: You have installed the php or your local server (localhost) or online?